# How to wrap text nodes with mixed <a> tags with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a newbie to jQuery. I want to make an chrome extension. But some webpages have HTML as follow, which I want to preprocess and make cleaner.

```
<div>
  Hello 
  <a href="#">World</a>
  !!!!!!
  <br />
  Nice to meet you
  <img src="#">
</div>
```

I want to wrap all the text nodes separated by `<br>` tags into `p` tags, but skipping over `a` tags in between, and finally delete the `<br>` tags. (It just skips over `a` tags, any other tag should not be skipped and the text should be wrapped up to that point). The above example should be transformed as following:

```
<div>
  <p>Hello <a href="#">World</a>!!!!!!</p>
  <p>Nice to meet you</p>
  <img src="#">
</div>
```

How can I do the above transformation using jQuery?

I find a related answer, but don't know how to skip over the `a` tags.

```
$("body br").each(function () {
  $.each([this.previousSibling, this.nextSibling], function() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3) { 
      $(this).wrap('<p></p>');
    }
    // Should skip over a tags
  });

  $(this).remove(); 
});
```

Another attempt, but failed (the last element to be merged is appears two times).

```js
$("body br").each(function() {
  $.each([this.previousSibling, this.nextSibling], function() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3) {
      $(this).wrap('<p></p>');
    }
    // Should skip over a tags
  });

  $(this).remove();
});

//Wrap all <br> tags with <p>
var to_be_deleted = new Array();
var just_finished = false;

function is_finished() {
  return just_finished;
}

function set_finished(val) {
  just_finished = val;
}

$('body br').each(function() {
  $.each([this.previousSibling, this.nextSibling], function() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3) { // 3 == text
      if ($(this).parent().is("p")) {
        console.log("Parent is p");
      }
      if (this.nextSibling) {

        var curr = this.nextSibling;
        var count = 0; // How many elements merged
        var till_now = $('<p class="merged_block">');
        $(till_now).append($(this).clone());
        while (curr) {
          if (curr.tagName === "A") {
            var a_elem = $(curr).clone();
            $(till_now).append(a_elem);
            to_be_deleted.push(curr);
            count++;

          } else if (curr.nodeType === 3) {
            var n_elem = $(curr).clone();
            $(till_now).append(n_elem);
            to_be_deleted.push(curr);
            count++;

          } else {
            break;
          }

          curr = curr.nextSibling;
        }

        if (count > 0) {
          $(this).before(till_now);
          $(this).remove();
          set_finished(true);
        }

      } else {
        if (is_finished()) {
          $(this).remove();
          set_finished(false);
        } else {
          $(this).wrap('<p></p>'); // Last <br/>
        }

      }
    }
  });

  $(this).remove(); //-- Kill the <br>
});

$.each(to_be_deleted, function(i, e) {
  $(e).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Hello <a href="#">World</a> blablah
  <br /> Nice to meet you
  <img src="#">
</div>
```

Comment: why do it this way and not fix your html ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Yes, but it is someone else page. I want to make chrome extension that will work over pages like this, so I wanted to preprocess the page and make it cleaner.

Comment: So again, everything until `br` **or** `img` gets wrapped in a paragraph? Or is there more?

Comment: @SalmanA Not specifically `img` but anything other than `a` should get wrapped in paragraph. For example `text<a>text<a>text<h1>h1</h1>` The text should be wrapped until `h1` tag.

Comment: I think the related answer was on the right track. You could modify it slightly so it's something like `if (this.tagName !== "A" && this.nodeType === 3) { $(this).wrap('<p></p>') };` and see if that helps. Also the example was missing a closing brace, not sure if that affects anything. A gist or fiddle also helps if all else fails

Comment: Ah... all inline elements get wrapped inside paragraph?

Comment: @SalmanA Yes you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dad = document.getElementById("dad"),
        container = document.getElementById("container"),
        elem = container.childNodes,
        parent = document.createElement("div"),
        newElem = document.createElement("p");

    while($(container).html() !== "") {
        if (elem[0].nodeName == "#text") {
            newElem.appendChild(elem[0]);
            elem.data = "";
        } else if (elem[0].nodeName == "BR") {
            parent.appendChild(newElem);
            newElem = document.createElement("p");
            container.removeChild(elem[0]);
        } else {
            newElem.appendChild(elem[0]);
            container.removeChild(elem[0]);
        }
    }
    parent.appendChild(newElem);
    newElem = document.createElement("p");

    dad.removeChild(container);
    parent.id = "container";
    dad.appendChild(parent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="dad">
  <div class="container" id="container">
    Hello 
    <a href="#">World</a>
    !!!!!!
    <br />
    Nice to meet you
    <img src="#">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: So, what's the question?